# "this" pointer in C (not C++)

Tags: c, function-pointers

I'm trying to create a stack in C for fun, and came up with the idea of using struct to represent the stack. Then I add function pointers to the struct for push() and pop() operations.

So far all is good it seems, but, for the implementation of the push() and pop() functions I need to refer to *this somehow. How can that (can it?) be done?

This is my struct

```
struct Stack {
    int *data;
    int current_size;
    int max_size;
    int (*push)(int);
    int (*pop)();
};
```

And as an example here's push

```
int push(int val) {
    if(current_size == max_size -1)
            return 0;

    data[current_size] = val;
    current_size++;

    return 1;
}
```

As you can imagine, the compiler has no idea what `current_size` is, as it would expect something like `stack->current_size`.

Is this possible to overcome somehow?

Comment: what's the point of function pointers in your stack struct?

Comment: To try to get an answer to if it's at all possible to call a stack of this type like this: `stack->push(10);`. Now, if the answer is not given here I can be pretty confident that it's indeed impossible.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's no implicit `this` in C. Make it explicit:

```
int push(Stack* self, int val) {
    if(self->current_size == self->max_size - 1)
            return 0;

    self->data[self->current_size] = val;
    (self->current_size)++;

    return 1;
}
```

You will of course have to pass the pointer to the struct into every call to `push` and similar methods.

This is essentially what the C++ compiler is doing for you when you define `Stack` as a class and `push` et al as methods.

Comment: That's the idea, but using `this` as a variable is awkward, if someone ever tries to include your C in a C++ program.

Comment: I could do this, but then there is no point in having the functions as pointers in the struct. If possible I'd like to just call `push(int val)`, even if things gets ugly. If the answer is that it's impossible to do, that is a satisfying answer as well.

Comment: There are many reasons other than `this` why including C code in a C++ source file is not valid and could lead to major bugs. Just don't do it. If `this` makes sense as a variable name (as it does here), use it.

Comment: @foo: There's still a point of putting the function pointers in the struct. You should never declare external functions with such generic names as `push` and `pop`, especially if the code might eventually be part of a library. So you'd either need to name them something like `foo_push` and `foo_pop`, or you could hide them as `static` in the implementation file for the stack and have `foo_allocstack` return a stack object with the function pointers set to point to these static functions. The latter solution has more overhead, but it could be useful.

Answer (score 4):

The typical approach in C is to have functions expect `this` as the first parameter.

```
int push(Stack *self, int val) 
{
  if (self->current_size == self->max_size -1) return 0;
  self->data[self->current_size++] = val;
  return 1;
}
```

This has the added benefit that, unless you need polymorphism, you don't need to put the functions in the stack, because you could just call `push(stack, 10)` instead of `stack->push(stack,10)`.

Comment: Thanks. That was my first approach, but I wanted to have some fun with function pointers and wanted to see how far it was possible to get C to get a C++ behavior. The purpose of this is to educate myself and experiment, nothing serious. I agree that using `push(stack, 10)` is the most sensible thing to do in C.

Answer (score 2):

In header file you can declare `static` `this` variable

```c
static struct Stack *this;
```

And then in `push` method you can use `this` variable

```c
static int push(int val) {
    if(this->current_size == this->max_size - 1)
            return 0;

    this->data[this->current_size] = val;
    (this->current_size)++;

    return 1;
}
```

The caveat is you have to manually set `this` variable through some method before you want to invoke other methods, eg:

```c
struct Stack {
    struct Stack (*_this)(struct Stack *); // <-- we create this method
    int *data;
    int current_size;
    int max_size;
    int (*push)(int);
    int (*pop)();
};
```

And then we can implement `_this` method as

```c
static struct Stack *_this(struct Stack *that)
{
    retrun this = that;
}
```

The example:

```c
struct Stack stack1, stack2;

... some initialization ...

stack1->_this(&stack1)->push(0);
stack1->push(1);
stack1->push(2);

stack2->_this(&stack2);
stack2->push(10);
stack2->push(20);
```

Comment: keep track which pointer currently pointed to this.

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't work like that. It's not an object oriented language. Functions that manipulate data structures need to take a pointer to the structure as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your function pointers aren't methods so they don't have any information about the calling object.  The only way to do what you want is to either pass in a pointer to the object, or make that pointer global (the latter is not recommended).

Comment: Well, that's not the ONLY way... you can actually retrieve a perfectly usable 'this' pointer from INSIDE of the member function.

... it's just NOT a good idea, due to portability concerns.


There's nothing wrong with passing it in as a 1st argument, as that's the industry standard way.  Anything else is usually a nasty 'code smell'

Answer (score 0):

Okay, but only because I hate it when people say something can't be done...

**You definitely CAN do this in C, but you very VERY shouldn't.**

In fact, it's such a monumentally terrible idea I don't even want to provide code examples in case someone just copy-pastes it into their project.

**Here's an outline:**

1. Design your typedef struct 'Class' such that it contains function pointers to all its member functions.
2. When a member function is called, it will be called as 'class->function()'
3. Realise that this appears, in your compiled code, as an indirect call that references the function pointer inside the structure.  It does this *(in your callers code)* using the address of the start of the structure and an offset to the specific member.
4. When you wake up inside of *'function()'* and need to know WHICH instance of the 'class' called you *(your 'this' pointer)* then what you're really needing IS the address of the structure that you were called via.
5. Using the compilers built-ins you can query your functions current return address, which will be the opcode immediately following the indirect call that called your function.
6. From this, any suitably motivated miscreant can fairly easily obtain a 'this' pointer.

But now, exactly, you do this is both compiler and target specific.

**Assuming GCC, See :**

void* **__builtin_return_address(** *unsigned int Level* **);** /* to find the call */

and, importantly, wrap the above call in...

void* **__builtin_extract_return_addr(** *void* addr* **);** /* for address safety */

In fact, your code can also extract the stack frames by level, too.  Using :

void* **__builtin_frame_address (** *unsigned int level* **)**;

It's not *too* difficult to figure out the rest with a little experimentation.

.

**Congratulations, you're now as dangerous as a toddler with a hand-grenade.**

So, YES, it is quite possible to extract the 'this' pointer of the structure you were called via, from within your callee function... You just SHOULDN'T... like, ever!

At least, never in production code.

The ONLY time this sort of thing is even remotely okay is if you're writing a payload for some malware or some sort of injection exploit.

**[Example]**

With type 'Class' having multiple instances, myClass1 and myClass2...

When called as **myClass2->function(** *params* **)**;

Your function() can use the compiler builtins and the callers last instruction to determine that it was called via myClass2's pointer, and return a pointer to 'myClass2' itself.

You can then re-cast this address pointer using (Class*) and store it in a LOCAL, NON-STATIC, *'this'* variable *(it makes no sense to store it in the structure, as that presents a 'catch-22' situation):*

Then, throughout the function body, simply use the regular conventions:

**this->memberVariable = 2;**

**this->memberFunction(params);**

And before anyone yells at me about how dangerous and non-portable this would be - I know!  I agree!

So, for the sake of all that is good and holy, just pass in a damned 'this pointer' as 1st parameter... y'know... like a competent coder!

.

**The ONLY right way:**

Just bite the worlds tiniest bullet and pass in a 'this' pointer as first argument, like this:

**pMyClass->function(** *pMyClass, ...* **);**

*or*

**MyClass.function(** *&MyClass, ...* **);**

Seriously, you **DO NOT** need the aggravation!

Answer (score -1):

Obviously you can have a Stack * member in the struct and then just initialize it with the address of the struct before you use the function pointers. Then make the Stack * a parameter on the function pointers.

Comment: You just locked your car with the keys inside.

Comment: That seems obvious. Did not thing about that, must try it out. Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering if different users on this site see questions before others. I don't see how a question like this can get four answers in less than one minute.

Comment: @foo - with this solution you still have the exact same problem - the functions that push and pop point to don't know anything about the calling object.

Comment: There's acually no good reason to have the Stack * as a member of the struct. The struct address needs to be passed into the functions that are called off the pointers.

Comment: Storing the pointer in the struct doesn't help because that data, the struct address, is available in the scope in which you call the function pointers.

Comment: @Thomas - The answers did indeed come within a minute after I posted the question. This place is great that way.

Answer (score -2):

Since your are going to have only one **Stack** structure (that you named *stack*, apparently), you could define it as a global variable. This would allow pop/push to refer to the *stack* variable directly.

You would do something like:

stack.current_size += 4;

or use the **->** operator if you decide to declare *stack* as a memory pointer to *Stack*.