# Function pointer in struct in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, function-pointers

I have tried to implement class-like ideas in C using a `struct`. My test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct test_struct
{
    int data;
    void(*func)(struct test_struct *);
} test_t;

void inc_data(test_t * this)
{
    this->data++;
}

int main(void)
{
    test_t test = { 0, inc_data };

    test.func(&test);

    printf("%d\r\n", test.data);
}
```

It's working but I need 1 more thing. I want function `func` do not need `struct test_struct *` as a parameter, just call `test.func()`

How can I do it?

I think we can use `#define` to replace `test.func(&test)` to `test.FUNC()` but I don't know how to do it.

There is another question [`this` pointer in C, not C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442580/this-pointer-in-c-not-c) that reads similarly, but it is actually different. I know there is no `this` pointer in C.  My question is just: is there any "trick" to do it? Like using `#define` or something else. Using a global variable is not a good answer because I will have many objects in my program.

Comment: Simulating a language into another language is like a vegetarian making meat from tofu. It makes no sense and it annoys everyone around.

Comment: Switch to C++ directly. Don't struggle with C.

Comment: Or take a look at [Object oriented programming with ANSI-C](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf), not perfect, but it does go a bit deeper into an approach.

Comment: You can approach the problem with macros: `#define SCALL0(s, m)        ((s).m(&(s)))` — `#define SCALLn(s, m, ...)   ((s).m(&(s), __VA_ARGS__))` — `#define PCALL0(p, m)        ((p)->m(p))` — `#define PCALLn(p, m, ...)   ((p)->m((p), __VA_ARGS__))`. The S-macros are for when the argument is an actual structure; the P-macros are for when the argument is a pointer to the structure. The 0-macros are for when the member function only takes the `this` pointer; the n-macros are for when the member function takes one or more other arguments. You might write: `SCALL0(test, func)` for example.

Comment: You might be able to use just one of the two sets of macros by applying the address: `PCALL0(&test, func)` for example.  You might be willing to use GCC-specific extensions to avoid needing the 0-vs-n distinction: `#define PCALL(p, m, ...) ((p)->m((p), ## __VA_ARGS))`.  Thus, the `PCALL` macro could be the only macro you need if you accept the reduced portability and the need to apply `&` to structures.  And if you accept the macro notation to call member functions.  It ain't the same as the C++ member function invocation, but C ain't C++.

Comment: Given your edit, do you want the duplication 'undone'?  It was marked duplicate by Community because you accepted the proposed duplicate.  If you're suffering from buyer's remorse, the question could be reopened.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: yes, I miss click and I dont know how to remove duplicate mark.

Comment: You can't remove the duplicate; people with enough reputation can do it single-handedly, and multiple people with less reputation could have combined to do it collectively.

Comment: Coming from the C++ side, I cannot resist pointing out that the C++ compiler calls member functions *without* storing a function pointer in the struct. And it does not require you to type the object name twice, have an extra parameter, or use an explicit `this->` everywhere. So doing this in C makes you type more to get less efficient code. Makes me wonder why you don't use the other language.  :-)

Comment: @Bo Persson: I am working on embedded system project so I can't use high-level programming language as C++.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments while the question was marked as a duplicate, you can play with the preprocessor and get fairly close to what you want.  It isn't exactly the notation you specify, but C is not C++.

You can approach the problem with macros:

```
#define SCALL0(s, m)        ((s).m(&(s)))
#define SCALLn(s, m, ...)   ((s).m(&(s), __VA_ARGS__))
#define PCALL0(p, m)        ((p)->m(p))
#define PCALLn(p, m, ...)   ((p)->m((p), __VA_ARGS__))
```

In all these macros, the `m` argument is the 'member function' to be called.  The S-macros are for when the `s` argument is an actual structure; the P-macros are for when the `p` argument is a pointer to the structure. The 0-macros are for when the member function only takes the this pointer; the n-macros are for when the member function takes one or more other arguments. You might write,  for example:

```
SCALL0(test, func);
```

You might be able to use just one of the two sets of macros by applying the address-of operator to actual structures, such as:

```
PCALL0(&test, func);
```

You might be willing to use a GCC-specific extension to the standard behaviour for [variadic macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html#Variadic-Macros) to avoid needing the 0-vs-n distinction:

```
#define PCALL(p, m, ...) ((p)->m((p), ## __VA_ARGS))
```

Thus, the PCALL macro could be the only macro you need if you accept the reduced portability and the need to apply `&` to structures…and if you accept the macro notation to call member functions. It ain't the same as the C++ member function invocation, but C ain't C++.

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct test_struct
{
    int data;
    void (*func0)(struct test_struct *);
    void (*func1)(struct test_struct *, int);
} test_t;

#define SCALL0(s, m)        ((s).m(&(s)))
#define SCALLn(s, m, ...)   ((s).m(&(s), __VA_ARGS__))
#define PCALL0(p, m)        ((p)->m(p))
#define PCALLn(p, m, ...)   ((p)->m((p), __VA_ARGS__))
#define PCALL(p, m, ...)    ((p)->m((p), ## __VA_ARGS__))

static void inc_data(test_t *this) { this->data++; }
static void dbl_data(test_t *this) { this->data *= 2; }
static void add_data(test_t *this, int add) { this->data += add; }
static void mul_data(test_t *this, int mul) { this->data *= mul; }

int main(void)
{
    test_t test = { 0, inc_data, add_data };
    test_t *pt1 = &(test_t){ 100, inc_data, add_data };
    test_t *pt2 = &(test_t){ 10, dbl_data, mul_data };
    test_t *pt3 = &(test_t){ -27, dbl_data, add_data };

    printf("Test SCALL0, SCALLn on structure:\n");
    printf("%d\n", test.data);
    test.func0(&test);
    printf("%d\n", test.data);
    test.func1(&test, 7);
    printf("%d\n", test.data);
    SCALL0(test, func0);
    printf("%d\n", test.data);
    SCALLn(test, func1, 100);
    printf("%d\n", test.data);

    printf("Test PCALL0, PCALLn on pointer:\n");
    printf("%d\n", pt1->data);
    pt1->func0(pt1);
    printf("%d\n", pt1->data);
    pt1->func1(pt1, 22);
    printf("%d\n", pt1->data);
    PCALL0(pt1, func0);
    printf("%d\n", pt1->data);
    PCALLn(pt1, func1, test.data);
    printf("%d\n", pt1->data);

    printf("Test PCALL0, PCALLn on another pointer:\n");
    printf("%d\n", pt2->data);
    pt2->func0(pt2);
    printf("%d\n", pt2->data);
    pt2->func1(pt2, 22);
    printf("%d\n", pt2->data);
    PCALL0(pt2, func0);
    printf("%d\n", pt2->data);
    PCALLn(pt2, func1, pt1->data);
    printf("%d\n", pt2->data);

    printf("Test PCALL on structure:\n");
    printf("%d\n", test.data);
    test.func0(&test);
    printf("%d\n", test.data);
    test.func1(&test, 22);
    printf("%d\n", test.data);
    PCALL(&test, func0);
    printf("%d\n", test.data);
    PCALL(&test, func1, pt1->data);
    printf("%d\n", test.data);

    printf("Test PCALL on pointer:\n");
    printf("%d\n", pt3->data);
    pt3->func0(pt3);
    printf("%d\n", pt3->data);
    pt3->func1(pt3, pt1->data);
    printf("%d\n", pt3->data);
    PCALL(pt3, func0);
    printf("%d\n", pt3->data);
    PCALL(pt3, func1, pt2->data);
    printf("%d\n", pt3->data);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Test SCALL0, SCALLn on structure:
0
1
8
9
109
Test PCALL0, PCALLn on pointer:
100
101
123
124
233
Test PCALL0, PCALLn on another pointer:
10
20
440
880
205040
Test PCALL on structure:
109
110
132
133
366
Test PCALL on pointer:
-27
-54
179
358
205398
```

You could create and use an `SCALL` macro, but it is probably better to use the `PCALL` macro instead.

Comment: Thank for your answer. It's not my expectations but enough.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ - which you are trying to emulate - there is a implicit `this` pointer as argument to each method. If you do not have such a similar pointer in your struct you will have to access global data when your method is called which is a bad idea.

Your function

```
void inc_data(test_t * this)
{
  this->data++;
}
```

Has that argument, but it relies on that you supply the argument when you call the function. If you were to remove it

```
void inc_data()
{...}
```

Then the function would need to operate on global data since there is no explicit relation between the function and the contents of the struct.

I would suggest - as other already have done to try out C++ instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thank for your answer.  I know there are not `this` pointer in C. But I just want to know "Have any "trick" to do?" Please check my edit section