# Initialize struct variable with previous one C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I want to have a structure like below:

```
typedef struct Mystruct
{
    double  p;
    double  x_min;
    double  x_max;
    double y_min;
    double y_max;
    double params[] = {x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max};
 };
```

My target is that the elements of the array `params` should be populated by `{ x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max}`.

Is there anyway to achieve this structure in [c](/questions/tagged/c)?

Comment: You can do that when you initialize all the `x_*` and `y_*` themselves...

Comment: why? Use a nested structure, take a pointer and later, use the address of the inner to populate the pointer.

Comment: Why? XY problem smell.

Comment: @n.m. - Literally a XY problem :D

Comment: (a) Do you want the array to have the same values as the other members even when they are changed or only after initialization? (b) Why are you trying to do this—what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Your code is declaring and typedefing a structure, not initializing it. That's the main issue. Second issue is the unnecessary data duplication.

Comment: This really smells very strongly like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you _actually_ trying to do? What _actual_ problem are you trying to resolve?

Comment: I voted to close because OP has not answered questions about their immediate intent (initialization only or actually making the same objects appear in different members) or ultimate purpose (what this is really needed for, so that a better alternative can be recommended).

Answer (score 1):

In C you cannot do this, instead you could write a function which does the initialization for structure instance.

```
typedef struct Mystruct
{
        double  p;
        double  x_min;
        double  x_max;
        double y_min;
        double y_max;
        double params[4];
}Mystruct;


Mystruct GetMystruct( double p, 
                      double x_min, 
                      double x_max, 
                      double y_min, 
                      double y_max)
{
    Mystruct my = { p, x_min,x_max,y_min,y_max, {x_min,x_max,y_min,y_max} } ;

    return my;
}
```

Then, example :

```
Mystruct m = GetMystruct( 0.0, 42.1, 42.2, 42.3,42.4 );
```

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to have two different views of the same structure members, one by name and one by index, then this can be achieved in most C implementations with:

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct foo
{
    double p;
    union
    {
        struct { double x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max; };
        double params[4];
    };
} foo;


int main(void)
{
    foo x = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        printf("%g\n", x.params[i]);
}
```

There are some theoretical hazards to this (notably ensuring that the internal `struct` is not padded), but it will work in normal C implementations, and the hazards can be guarded against. (Checking that the size of the internal `struct` equals the size of the array will guard against padding. In order to check the size, you will need to give that `struct` a tag so it has a name.)

This uses a union to make the named members the same as the array elements (not just initialized to be the same, but to actually use the same member), and it uses anonymous `struct` and `union` to make the names of the members in the inner aggregates usable as names of members of the outer `struct.`

Answer (score 0):

**No you can't do that**. You can't initialized member inside the declaration of structure. ***Because structure declaration defines a type not a variable***. The way you showed it. Keeping a set of variables which are dependent among themselves.  Even if you could why would you do that? Simply have an array.

```
typedef struct Mystruct
{
        double  p;
        double params[4];
};
```

Now with this you can do the initialization part yourself. Or if you need both which is less likely you can keep both of them. By that I mean you can keep those 4 variables and keep an array and then while initializing you can explicitly set the content yourself. No way to wrap it like you did. Then you initialze like this

```
struct MyStruct mystruct = {
   10.0, 
   { 5, 6, 7, 8 }
};
```

Also *if you want to keep two sets of variable being initialized with the same value you can follow the same method as shown above*. But it is really meaningless given that it  is nothing other two different variables having same values.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to share the memory between the XY params and the entries in the array using an `union`:

```
typedef struct Mystruct
{
   double  p;
   union {
      struct {
         double  x_min;
         double  x_max;
         double y_min;
         double y_max;
      };
      double params[] = {x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max};
};
```

This would mean that the xy values would always be the same as the ones in the array

Answer (score 0):

you can define a function inside the `struct` that  initializes /sets the `params` array to the desired values, with the function containing a *self-reference* ( `self` )  to its containing structure. however the values in the `params` array and will only get 'synchronized' if this function is called ...

an example for this method is in ["this" pointer in C (not C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442580/this-pointer-in-c-not-c) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


    typedef struct MyStruct
    {
        double  p;
        double  x_min;
        double  x_max;
        double y_min;
        double y_max;
        double params[4] ;
        void (*setParams)();

     }MyStruct;

    void setParams(MyStruct* self) {
        self->params[0]= self->x_min;
        self->params[1]= self->x_max;
        self->params[2]= self->y_min;
        self->params[3]= self->y_max;
    }

    int main (int argc, char * argv[])
    {
    MyStruct myStruct = {1.24, 2.0, 4.0, 2.0, 4.0, {0,0,0,0}, NULL };
    printf("%f, %f, %f, %f \n", myStruct.params[0], myStruct.params[1], myStruct.params[2], myStruct.params[3]  );
    setParams(&myStruct);
    printf("%f, %f, %f, %f \n", myStruct.params[0], myStruct.params[1], myStruct.params[2], myStruct.params[3]  );

    return 0;
    }
```

however to *'synchronize'* you have to call `setParams()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want 2 different copies of the same data, simply use common sense:

```
typedef struct 
{
  double x_min;
  double x_max;
  double y_min;
  double y_max;
} xy_stuff;

typedef struct 
{
    double   p;
    xy_stuff xy;
    xy_stuff params;
} Mystruct;

...

Mystruct ms = 
{ 
  .p      = 1.0,
  .xy     = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0},
  .params = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0},
};
```